# ImportError: cannot import name 'print_result' from 'utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/utils/__init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

I am trying to import utils in Python from Google Colab and use this function to display the result. Whenever, I try to use print_result() it shows the ImportError. I don't know what is wrong. I've already installed utils, also imported it. Can somebody provide solution?

I am trying to use the print_result() to display the result in program. This functions is imported from utils library of Python. Though I've installed & imported the library I'm getting this error, whenever I use the function.
ImportError: cannot import name 'print_result' from 'utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/utils/**init**.py)

Comment: Are you sure you really got what you intended? If you installed it using pip, you probably got this: https://pypi.org/project/utils/ - and it really doesn't have such a funciton

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.